# How to automatially detect status of the network interface with NM

Tags: networking, scripts, network-manager, vpn

I have eth0 device and tun0 device (VPN) and I would like to automatically detect if any of these devices changes status, i.e. they are up or down.

In each case, I would like to automatically call a predefined script. So:

- if eth0 goes down, I would like to call script 1
- if tun0 goes down, script 2
- if tun0 goes up, script 3

How to do that with NetworkManager?

For tun0, I can use `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto tun0
iface tun0 inet manual
    up /bin/sh /home/matej/tun-up.sh
    down /bin/sh /home/matej/tun-down.sh
```

What about eth0, since network is managed by Network Manager?

Comment: [Dispatcher scripts](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/NetworkManager.html) do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot! This is what I did:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02-events
```

With the content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ "$1" = "eth0" ] && [ "$2" = "down" ] ; then
echo "eth0 is down!" >> /home/matej/dispatch.txt
fi

if [ "$1" = "tun0" ] && [ "$2" = "down" ] ; then
echo "VPN is down!" >> /home/matej/dispatch.txt
fi

if [ "$1" = "tun0" ] && [ "$2" = "up" ] ; then
echo "VPN is up!" >> /home/matej/dispatch.txt
fi
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02-events
```

Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

This works as expected, but when I unplug the ethernet cable, there is around 10 seconds timeout, before NetworkManager detects an event. Could this be shortened to let's say 5 seconds?

Comment: Restarting NetworkManager is seldom necessary nor correct.

Comment: For the delay when unplugging the cable see `device.carrier-wait-timeout` in `man NetworkManager.conf`.